# creating subprojects in bottle

Tags: python, frameworks, module, bottle

I'm just starting Python web development, and have chosen Bottle as my framework of choice.

I'm trying to have a project structure that is modular, in that I can have a 'core' application that has modules built around it, where these modules can be enabled/disabled during setup (or on the fly, if possible...not sure how I would set that up tho).

My 'main' class is the following:

```
from bottle import Bottle, route, run
from bottle import error
from bottle import jinja2_view as view

from core import core

app = Bottle()
app.mount('/demo', core)

#@app.route('/')
@route('/hello/<name>')
@view('hello_template')
def greet(name='Stranger'):
    return dict(name=name)

@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return 'Nothing here, sorry'

run(app, host='localhost', port=5000)
```

My 'subproject' (i.e. module) is this:

```
from bottle import Bottle, route, run
from bottle import error
from bottle import jinja2_view as view

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/demo')
@view('demographic')
def greet(name='None', yob='None'):
    return dict(name=name, yob=yob)

@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return 'Nothing here, sorry'
```

When I go to `http://localhost:5000/demo` in my browser, it shows a 500 error.  The output from the bottle server is:

```
localhost - - [24/Jun/2012 15:51:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 720
localhost - - [24/Jun/2012 15:51:27] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 742
localhost - - [24/Jun/2012 15:51:27] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 742
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 737, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 582, in mountpoint
    rs.body = itertools.chain(rs.body, app(request.environ, start_response))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

The folder structure is:

```
index.py
views (folder)
|-->hello_template.tpl
core (folder)
|-->core.py
|-->__init__.py
|-->views (folder)
|--|-->demographic.tpl
```

I have no idea what I'm doing (wrong) :)

Anyone have any idea how this can/should be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are Passing the module "core" to the mount() function. Instead you have to pass the bottle app object to the mount() function, So the call would be like this.

```
app.mount("/demo",core.app)
```

Here are formal docs for the mount() function.

> ```
> mount(prefix, app, **options)[source]
> ```
>
> Mount an application (Bottle or plain WSGI) to a specific URL
>   prefix.
>  Example:
>
> ```
> root_app.mount('/admin/', admin_app)
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>    prefix – path prefix or mount-point. If it ends in a
>   slash, that slash is mandatory.
>   **app – an instance of Bottle or a WSGI application**